# create client certificate adding certain ip address to certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, openssl, ssl-certificate

I need to create  a client certificate that should include certain ip address which will be installed on a particular computer and thus communicate with server that will grab ip address from client certificate. So, I want to know is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to use the certificate to PASS the IP address?  Or are you trying to validate the computer BASED ON the IP address?  A little more insight would be handy.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to use server certificate on server and client certificate on browser. Client certificate must contain additional information like ip=192.168.2.2. So, my question is:- is it possible to add additional information on client certificate. If possible, is it also possible to get that information on server which is using server certificate. the client and server certificate have common CA certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, custom information, depending on the type can be added to a certificate.  Here's a reasonable article on how to use [OpenSSL for custom content](http://www.drchaos.com/creating-custom-certificate-signing-request-with-openssl-for-ciscoise/)

It's still not exactly clear what you're trying to do, but Subject Alternate Name (SAN) may be a  good start, depending on what you're looking for.

[Here's a topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48639/does-critical-subjectaltname-ipx-x-x-x-on-an-ssl-client-certificate-limit-where) for what Subject Alternate Name may be able to do for you.

If you're looking for all the [x.500 attributes](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.5.4.html), you might find, userCertificate or uniqueIdentifier suitable.

[Here's also a good thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616686/how-do-i-add-additional-information-to-certificate-service-request-csr) on using non-standard fields in the certificate, so long as your not looking for global-compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't require SAN. I just wanted to add custom information not custom certificate signing request. I have got client and server certificate. My server rejects unauthorized users. so, client certificate is needed to get access to server from browser. Lets say I have got information as "user=username". I wanted to add this on my client certificate. How can I add this information on my client certificate? I also want to know if I can retrieve this information on my server that only contains server certificate not client certificate.

Comment: Well, see, that's why it's not clear what you're trying to do.  How is "ip.1 = 192.168.2.2" (link above) different from "ip=192.168.2.2" (your comment above)?  To your second point, if you've already got the client certificate, there will be no way to change its content (or rather, use it for authentication) without generating a new CSR and having the CA re-sign the cert.

Comment: Ok, lets forget about ip. I want to generate a new CSR that includes user=username after country,organization,locality,CN, email address,etc that will be included on certificate signing request. So, how can I achieve it?

Comment: My problem was related to OID in openssl config file. I am trying to fix it. Thanks for your support.